# react native pdf view error resolving dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been stuck with this problem in react native version 0.64 latest. pdf view  is throwing an error while configuring. I don't understand and not found the right answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more information about this error on this question: ["JCenter is at end of life" android lint warning, what is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400264/jcenter-is-at-end-of-life-android-lint-warning-what-is-the-replacement/67296946#67296946)

You need to add `mavenCentral()` to `android/build.gradle`

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() //add this
    }
```

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() //add this
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working now fine @james-z

Comment: return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\KYLS_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\kyls\MainApplication.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
location: class MainApplication
C:\KYLS_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\kyls\MainApplication.java:76: error: illegal parenthesized expression
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
^
Note: C:\KYLS_App\android\app\src\debug\java\com\kyls\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s