# carouselview on android was not found in the project or libraries

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use the `carouselView` in my project following a tutorial but I cant get it running.

1 - I added the dependency to the `build:gradle`:
`implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'` and sync

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.carouselview"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
```

[image]

2 - Then I try to use the following code:

```xml
    <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
        android:id="@+id/carouselView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:pageColor="#00000000"
        app:radius="6dp"
        app:slideInterval="3000"
        app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

But I'm getting this error and I don't know why

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Edit: error output

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Suprakids\AndroidStudioProjects\CarouselView
```

> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 5: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 6: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 7: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 481ms
20 actionable tasks: 20 executed

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches and restart and sync this should fix it. as i see and tried it your code does not have any problems must be android studio.

To clear Android Studio's cache and bring it out of its state of confusion, select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button. Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I did all the steps you mention but I'm having the problem yet.

`Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.`

Trying to rebuild project

Comment: could you update the answer and add app gradle and that error as full. also i found this in [issues on the library github try this.](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview/issues/128)

Comment: I tried the issue that you said and same error. I pasted all the error trace when trying to rebuild the project.

Comment: Please share settings.gradle or if you just don't see jcenter( )
 there add it like this 
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
} 

and it should build successfully.

Comment: althoug Jcenter is not recommended. You can ready more about in this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400264/jcenter-is-at-end-of-life-android-lint-warning-what-is-the-replacement#:~:text=The%20documentation%20states%3A,artifacts%20until%20February%201%2C%202022.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `jcenter()` in your `settings.gradle` file like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter( )
}
```

}